# Min vertical distance between two curves without iteration (the equation of one of the curves is unknown)

Tags: curves, maxima-minima

I want to find the min vertical distance between two curves:

one of my curves is linear.

But I can't fit a curve to my other curve so the equation is unknown.

calculation of the min vertical distance with iteration causes my code to the malfunctioning behavior.

So I should calculate the min distance without iteration:

IS THERE ANY WAY?

one of my curves is at the following link:
[The most accurate curve fitting function for the attached plot (It is a thermodynamic properties behavior)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302742/the-most-accurate-curve-fitting-function-for-the-attached-plot-it-is-a-thermody)

Comment: Please post the data from which you have drawn the curve.

Comment: The data is the enthalpy function of the humid air at the saturated condition. you can find the data at the link:http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=48827370308950950619

Comment: What do the horizontal/vertical axes represent?

Comment: x: temperature, y: enthalpy

Comment: I want to find the min enthalpy difference (between two flows) in a simultaneous equation solver software (EES), and that's why I don't want an iteration method

Comment: Curve fitting is definitely possible. If you do not want to do that, you don't have the equation of the first curve. How will you find the minimum distance then? What is the equation of the second curve?

Comment: It is a simple linear curve. You can see it as the red line in the figure:https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0011916416300509-gr2.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96625/discussion-between-ptds-and-meng).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can

1. Either do a "point by point" comparison between the straight line and the curve
   [which you probably don't want]
2. Or you can fit an "appropriate curve" and then calculate the minimum distance between the curve and the straight line. Here, the "appropriate curve" probably comes from "Michaelis–Menten enzyme kinetic model function" [Please Google it]

I can give you more details on how to fit the above curve if that helps.